# Get the data from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm sending request response to app class via redux. 
And I receive it in props as I can console.log(this.props.data);

But I get this nested array full of objects

I've tried
`console.log(this.props.data[0].PromiseValue);`

which results in undefined

```
[Promise]
0: Promise
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
headers: {pragma: "no-cache", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", cache-control: "public, max-age=14400", expires: "Mon, 01 Apr 2019 22:25:19 GMT"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to bind to the "then" event of the promise? Something like this:

```
this.props.data[0].then(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: thanx alot your comment was very helpful i got it this way  this.props.data[0].then(value => {
      console.log(value.data);
    });